# Nutiteq issue with spatialite on iOS, init exception - sqlite3_auto_extension EXEC_BAD_ACCESS address 0x300

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, spatialite

I create swift project. add SpatialDBKit pod and some other lib.

When i try to open database with

```
let db = SpatialDatabase(path: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myfile", ofType: "spatialite") )
```

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x300)

```
spatialite_init (int verbose)
{
/* used when SQLite initializes as an ordinary lib 
   OBSOLETE - strongly discuraged !!!!!
*/

#ifndef OMIT_GEOS       /* initializing GEOS */
    initGEOS (geos_warning, geos_error);
#endif /* end GEOS  */

    sqlite3_auto_extension ((void (*)(void)) init_spatialite_extension);
    spatialite_splash_screen (verbose);
}
```

at sqlite3_auto_extension method call.

Please note that i open it with FMDB without any issue.

**UPDATE:**

I found that i have issue pod. 
when copy file directly from github and replace, issue fixed!

Comment: Have you added sqlite3 to your frameworks?

Comment: yes, but i have issue with spatialite and not sqlite. also app crash at   sqlite3_auto_extension, means sqlite init successfully and try to init spatialite extention

Comment: I am struggling to integrate SpatialiteDBKit with my swift project. Would it be possible for you to share with me a working demo project or help me?

Answer (score 0):

I see that pod has issue.

see https://github.com/andreacremaschi/SpatialDBKit/issues/21